# Mysql LEFT Join on big data table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called "tables_data_info" where is stored some of the data relative to different tables. Data like "created time", "editing time", "editing user", "create by user id" etc. I'm using this table because there was a dynamic php script that generate it automatically.
But, when i have a huge number of record ( 15k in this case ) the query getting very very very slow, and take "minutes" to do his job! But i'm not selecting all 15k records, i'm limiting to select 10 records at all!
A simple query:

`SELECT pd.id, pd.title, pd.sell_price, pd.available_qt, tdi.createtime, tdi.lastupdatetime, tdi.create_member_id, tdi.create_group_id, tdi.last_update_member_id, tdi.last_update_group_id FROM zd_products AS pd LEFT JOIN zd_tables_data_info AS tdi ON ( tdi.targetid = pd.id and tdi.table_name = 'products' ) ORDER by pd.title ASC LIMIT 0, 10`

How can i run this query differently but more efficiently ?

Here the table structure:

**zd_products**

```
CREATE TABLE `zd_products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `internalcode` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ean13_jan_code` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upc_code` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
  `product_tags` longtext,
  `buy_price` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sell_price` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fiscal_tax_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `box_width` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `box_height` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `box_depth` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `box_weight` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `shipment_extra_price` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `available_qt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allow_purchase_out_stock` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_title` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15730 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**zd_tables_data_info**

```
CREATE TABLE `zd_tables_data_info` (
  `table_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `targetid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_member_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_group_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update_member_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update_group_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `createtime` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastupdatetime` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `INDEX` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19692 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Do you have indexes created on those tables? the query itself looks ok, if it's taking that long, sounds like an index prob. to me.

Comment: in order to determine the "top 10" records based on order, it needs to query and sort the entire table ... so yes, the optimizer is querying all 15k records.

Comment: I agree with indexes, also add foreign key to targetid for your join. Depending on what results you want you can try to add "DISTINCT pd.id as d_pdid," as the first thing you SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not particularly big.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT pd.id, pd.title, pd.sell_price, pd.available_qt,
       tdi.createtime, tdi.lastupdatetime, tdi.create_member_id, tdi.create_group_id,
       tdi.last_update_member_id, tdi.last_update_group_id
FROM zd_products pd LEFT JOIN
     zd_tables_data_info tdi
     ON tdi.targetid = pd.id and tdi.table_name = 'products'
ORDER by pd.title ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

You can improve performance of this query with indexes.  The two that come to mind are `zd_products(title, id)` and `zd_tables_data_info(targetid, table_name)`.  Try these and see if they help.  You can create these indexes either in the `create table` statement (or `alter table`) or by using:

```
create index zd_products_title_id on zd_products(title, id);
create index zd_tables_data_info_targetid_table_name on zd_tables_data_info(targetid, table_name);
```

If not, put `explain` in front of your query and then edit your question with the resulting plan.

Comment: What do you mean with indexes ? The relations between tables or the index keys ?

Comment: I've added the tables structure in the answer

Comment: Oh! With the indexes the query is much much more faster! Thanks! Could you advise me a good read to understand more about the indexes ? How the declaration of this indexes help the query to do a better job ?